# Who typed the incorrect credentials during Event 4625?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

During a 4625 windows event (failed logon) such as the below who has actually typed the incorrect credentials?

a) Was it the user on computer logged in as paulb incorrectly typing admin-user credentials?

Or b) is it the user logged in as admin-user incorrectly typing paulb's credentials?

```
WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_FAILURE(4625): 
Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing: (no user): no domain: 
M-P-BO-SOA1: An account failed to log on. 
Subject: 
    Security ID: S-1-4-11-123456789-123456789-123456789-1234
    Account Name: admin-user
    Account Domain: WINSERVER01
    Logon ID: 0x6772f 
    Logon Type: 2 

Account For Which Logon Failed: 
    Security ID: S-1-0-0 
    Account Name: paulb
    Account Domain: 
    Failure Information: 
    Failure Reason: %%2313 
    Status: 0xc000006d 
    Sub Status: 0xc000006a 
    Process Information: 
    Caller Process ID: 0xfb8 
    Caller Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\dllhost.exe 
    Network Information: 
    Workstation Name: WINSERVER01 Source 
    Network Address: - 
    Source Port: - 

Detailed Authentication Information: 
    Logon Process: Advapi Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0 Transited Services: - Package Name (NTLM only): - 
    Key Length: 0 
    This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Account admin-user (subject) tried to logon as paulb interactively (logon type 2), which failed because the password is wrong (0xC000006d/0xC000006A)